# Service fabric when to use remote call vs reverse proxy to communicate with microservices

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have setup 2 noted type cluster on FrontEnd and another BackEnd. The FrontEnd has stateless services and the Backend has Statefull and actor services. Now I have seen examples where they use reverse proxy and **http://** calls to communicate with stateful services, and other places where they use Remote calls calling **fabric://** When should each be used if there is data intensive transfers happening between Frontend and BackEnd node types which would be better protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Actually **fabric://** isn't a protocol itself, it's just a syntax for Service Fabric Naming Service to resolve actual location of your service. Remoting is a better choice if you don't have to expose your service to external clients, since it will choose protocol depending on locations on client and service (may use interprocess communication in case both are located on the same node) while using **http://** sticks you to only this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

*The **fabric://** is just an Uri Scheme. It is used to identify named services, like: **fabric://MyApp/MyService***

There is no right answer to this question, there are many variables to take into account to select the right approach.

You can use both and it will be absolutely fine.

**It far more than that, but a a simple overview I can give is:**

Using HTTP communication, the services depends only on each other endpoints, and both can be treated isolated from each other during development and deployment, they will communicate even when you change services versions and tech-stack. You can use different technologies like: Java, GO, NodeJS and still have a smooth communication between your services.

Using Remoting, you might get faster communication, but higher coupling between the services, because both need to understand same interfaces and entities used for communication, to keep them in sync(compatible) will most of the time require to deploy new version of both services together.

.

If performance is not an issue at start, I would suggest go simple with HTTP, and migrate if does not attend your demands.